# increase value in array

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to make multi array like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["Test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["opgang1"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
      }
      ["opgang2"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
      }
      ["opgang3"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(0)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is i need the y values to increase like the x value. X values increase for each "etage" and the y values need to increase for each "opgang".

I have tryed alot to get that done, this is the code i have got so fare:

```
$projektNavn = "Test";
$opgange = 3;
$etage = 2;
$temp = array();

$dele = array(
    'varm' => array('x1' => 0, 'x2' => 0, 'y1' => 0, 'y2' => 0)
//    'kold' => array('x1' => '200', 'x2' => '200', 'y1' => '200', 'y2' => '200')
);

for ($i = $etage; $i >= 1; $i--) {

    $varmeX1 = $dele['varm']['x1'] + 50;
    $varmeX2 = $dele['varm']['x2'] + 150;
    $dele['varm']['x1'] = $varmeX1;
    $dele['varm']['x2'] = $varmeX2;

    $etag['etage' . $i] = $dele;
}

for ($j = 1; $j <= $opgange; $j++) {

    $varmeY1 = $dele['varm']['y1'] + 100;
    $varmeY2 = $dele['varm']['y2'] + 200;
    $dele['varm']['y1'] = $varmeY1;
    $dele['varm']['y2'] = $varmeY2;

//        $temp = $dele;

    $opgang['opgang' . $j] = $etag;
}

$projekt = array(
    $projektNavn => array(
        $opgang
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($projekt);
echo "</pre><br>";
```

I know that `$varmeY1` and `$varmeY2`  not are added to `$etag` and therefor are `0`, I tried all I know, so hope some of you can help my here :)

Final result need to be:

```
array(1) {
  ["Test"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["opgang1"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(200)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(200)
          }
        }
      }
      ["opgang2"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(200)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(400)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(200)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(400)
          }
        }
      }
      ["opgang3"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["etage2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(50)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(150)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(600)
          }
        }
        ["etage1"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["varm"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["x1"]=>
            int(100)
            ["x2"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y1"]=>
            int(300)
            ["y2"]=>
            int(600)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little hard to follow, but if I understand, you want almost a i x j matrix, with `i` being `opgange` and `j` being `etage`. Please correct me if I am wrong - if not, this should get you most of the way - you just needed to nest the loops.

```
<?php

$projektNavn = "Test";
$opgange     = 3;
$etage       = 2;

$dele = [
    'varm' => ['x1' => 0, 'x2' => 0, 'y1' => 0, 'y2' => 0]
//    'kold' => array('x1' => '200', 'x2' => '200', 'y1' => '200', 'y2' => '200')
];

$data = [];
$temp = $dele;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $opgange; $i++)
{
    if (!isset($data['opgang' . $i])) {
        $data['opgang' . $i] = [];
    }

    $temp['varm']['y1'] += 100;
    $temp['varm']['y2'] += 200;

    $prev = null;

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $etage; $j++)
    {
        $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j] = (null !== $prev) ? $prev : $dele;

        $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j]['varm']['x1'] += 50;
        $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j]['varm']['x2'] += 150;
        $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j]['varm']['y1'] = $temp['varm']['y1'];
        $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j]['varm']['y2'] = $temp['varm']['y2'];

        $prev = $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j];
    }
}

unset($temp);

$projekt = [
    $projektNavn => [
        $data
    ]
];

print_r($projekt);
```

Output of the above is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [opgang1] => Array
                        (
                            [etage1] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 50
                                            [x2] => 150
                                            [y1] => 100
                                            [y2] => 200
                                        )

                                )

                            [etage2] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 100
                                            [x2] => 300
                                            [y1] => 100
                                            [y2] => 200
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [opgang2] => Array
                        (
                            [etage1] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 50
                                            [x2] => 150
                                            [y1] => 200
                                            [y2] => 400
                                        )

                                )

                            [etage2] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 100
                                            [x2] => 300
                                            [y1] => 200
                                            [y2] => 400
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [opgang3] => Array
                        (
                            [etage1] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 50
                                            [x2] => 150
                                            [y1] => 300
                                            [y2] => 600
                                        )

                                )

                            [etage2] => Array
                                (
                                    [varm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x1] => 100
                                            [x2] => 300
                                            [y1] => 300
                                            [y2] => 600
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I need the final result to be like this:

Comment: @Krabsen I have updated the supplied code, I think I misunderstood your requirement the first time around. I have used some newer PHP syntax there ([null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) from PHP 7 and the short-array syntax from PHP 5.4) - if that's a problem let me know.

Comment: I get a syntax error here: $data['opgang' . $i]['etage' . $j] = $prev ?? $dele;

Comment: @Krabsen Ahh. In that case, you're using PHP 5.x I assume. I've changed the code to be PHP 5.x compatible. Try now.

Comment: @Krabsen awesome :) if it helped, please go ahead and accept the answer!

Comment: Who do i do that? Was my first post in here :)